# Transaction blocking in ReportServerTempdb of SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I am getting some transaction blocking in ReportserverTempdb.
Below is the message I am getting;
"The transactions span multiple databases on the same instance"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two datasets that are from different databases are showing in one report at the same time.